# Send EOF to PyCharm console in Windows

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, eof

I'm learning PyCharm IDE on Windows.
How can I send end-of-file signal to it's debugging console?
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> does not work.

Comment: I've added the issue on PyCharm's YouTrack page: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-33840

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you cannot. Here are the list of command you can do to the PyCharm debugger [Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/debug-tool-window.html)

Answer (score 3):

Per [this answer from 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30762379/8033766), you can send EOF in Linux/Windows with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> and Mac with <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> in IntelliJ. I just tested it in PyCharm and it works there as well.

Comment: This works on Mac IntelliJ 2021.1 and is the answer that helped me. The way Jetbrains IDEs operate I would imagine it works on them all.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Windows is a whole different story. Mac and Linux are both Unix systems, CTRL-D actually sends EOF in Unix. You can end your terminal session, finish cat command (e.g. `cat > file.txt`) with that combination. AFAIK, there is no such command in Windows.