# How to run c++ and javascript client code (hackerrank style) on local machine

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, stdin, eof

I am working on learning C++ and Javascript by solving Hackerrank problems. Right now C++ compiles but when I run it stalls. The same with my JavaScript. I would like to learn to feed in data for test cases like they do on the platform. For example:
If I have this code in C++:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
vector<string> split_string(string);

// Complete the countApplesAndOranges function below.
void countApplesAndOranges(int s, int t, int a, int b, vector<int> apples, vector<int> oranges) {
    int count_a = 0;
    int count_b = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < apples.size(); i++){
        // apples[i] += a;
        apples[i] += a;
        if (s <= apples[i] && apples[i] <= t )
            count_a +=1;

        // cout << apples[i] << ;
    }
    // for (auto i: apples)
    //     // cout << i << ' ';

    // cout << endl;    
    for (int i = 0; i < oranges.size(); i++){

        // apples[i] += a;
        oranges[i] += b;
        if (s <= oranges[i] && oranges[i] <= t )
            count_b +=1;
        // cout << oranges[i] << "";
    }
    // for (auto i: oranges)
    //     // cout << i << ' ';

    cout << count_a << endl;
    cout << count_b;



}

int main()
{
    string st_temp;
    getline(cin, st_temp);

    vector<string> st = split_string(st_temp);

    int s = stoi(st[0]);

    int t = stoi(st[1]);

    string ab_temp;
    getline(cin, ab_temp);

    vector<string> ab = split_string(ab_temp);

    int a = stoi(ab[0]);

    int b = stoi(ab[1]);

    string mn_temp;
    getline(cin, mn_temp);

    vector<string> mn = split_string(mn_temp);

    int m = stoi(mn[0]);

    int n = stoi(mn[1]);

    string apples_temp_temp;
    getline(cin, apples_temp_temp);

    vector<string> apples_temp = split_string(apples_temp_temp);

    vector<int> apples(m);

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        int apples_item = stoi(apples_temp[i]);

        apples[i] = apples_item;
    }

    string oranges_temp_temp;
    getline(cin, oranges_temp_temp);

    vector<string> oranges_temp = split_string(oranges_temp_temp);

    vector<int> oranges(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int oranges_item = stoi(oranges_temp[i]);

        oranges[i] = oranges_item;
    }

    countApplesAndOranges(s, t, a, b, apples, oranges);

    return 0;
}

vector<string> split_string(string input_string) {
    string::iterator new_end = unique(input_string.begin(), input_string.end(), [] (const char &x, const char &y) {
        return x == y and x == ' ';
    });

    input_string.erase(new_end, input_string.end());

    while (input_string[input_string.length() - 1] == ' ') {
        input_string.pop_back();
    }

    vector<string> splits;
    char delimiter = ' ';

    size_t i = 0;
    size_t pos = input_string.find(delimiter);

    while (pos != string::npos) {
        splits.push_back(input_string.substr(i, pos - i));

        i = pos + 1;
        pos = input_string.find(delimiter, i);
    }

    splits.push_back(input_string.substr(i, min(pos, input_string.length()) - i + 1));

    return splits;
}
```

How would I go about "feeding" it inputs.

Similarly, for the JavaScript:

```
'use strict';

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');

let inputString = '';
let currentLine = 0;

process.stdin.on('data', inputStdin => {
    inputString += inputStdin;
});

process.stdin.on('end', _ => {
    inputString = inputString.replace(/\s*$/, '')
        .split('\n')
        .map(str => str.replace(/\s*$/, ''));

    main();
});

function readLine() {
    return inputString[currentLine++];
}

// Complete the countApplesAndOranges function below.
function countApplesAndOranges(s, t, a, b, apples, oranges) {
    let count_a = 0
    let count_b = 0

    for (let i = 0; i < apples.length; i++){
        apples[i] += a

        if (s <= apples[i] && apples[i] <= t)
            count_a += 1

    }
    for (let i = 0; i < oranges.length; i++){
        oranges[i] += b
        if (s <= oranges[i] && oranges[i] <= t)
            count_b += 1

    }


    console.log(count_a)
    console.log(count_b)
}

function main() {
    const st = readLine().split(' ');

    const s = parseInt(st[0], 10);

    const t = parseInt(st[1], 10);

    const ab = readLine().split(' ');

    const a = parseInt(ab[0], 10);

    const b = parseInt(ab[1], 10);

    const mn = readLine().split(' ');

    const m = parseInt(mn[0], 10);

    const n = parseInt(mn[1], 10);

    const apples = readLine().split(' ').map(applesTemp => parseInt(applesTemp, 10));

    const oranges = readLine().split(' ').map(orangesTemp => parseInt(orangesTemp, 10));

    countApplesAndOranges(s, t, a, b, apples, oranges);
}
```

I understand I could do this manually - by hardcoding local-variables to main() but I would like to learn about C++ - getline() function as well as JavaScript - process.stdin.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Do not try to learn to program through hackerrank. Use a book.

Comment: Check out a tutorial on C++, e.g. the [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial) one. How to call your program and give it input and arguments is very much operating system dependent, if you don't say what you use, we can't help at all. Posting a program asking for something completely unrelated to the program details is of no use, by the way. Same goes for Javascript, of which I know next to nothing, so no recommendations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the C++, you have to add the input: eg.

```
7 11 
5 15
3 2
-2 2 1
5 -6
```

It must be the exact number of lines as there are variables, or redirect the input from a file ie.

```
$ ./a.out < input.txt
```

For the JavaScript you must either: 
Redirect the input:

```
$ node program.js < input.txt
```

or add lines and press  to signify the end of input stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`pipe`**`operator` to feed the input from a file

```
$ cat input.txt | node main.js
```

---

---

*[ only works in **Unix**-based machine like MacBook, Linux, Ubuntu... ]*

For the JavaScript, after typing the input into shell, you can press **`Ctrl + D`** to sends `EOF`(end-of-file) to trigger the event handler in `process.stdin.on("end", ...)` .

As mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32494537/3785719), in Microsoft Windows, the readline interface does not support `^D`(Ctrl + D) by default