# How to run a JavaScript solution from HackerRank on Idea / WebStorm IDE?

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, debugging, webstorm

Say you want to run / debug a [HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/) solution locally on your WebStorm / IntelliJ Idea IDE for for macOS before submitting it. What are the needed steps, considering node.js is already installed in your machine?

Sample `Hello.js` file as below:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

function processData(input) {
  const ws = fs.createWriteStream(process.env.OUTPUT_PATH);

  var i, result = "";
  for (i = 0; i < parseInt(input); i++) {
    result += 'Hello - ' + i + '\n';
  }
  ws.write(result + "\n");
  ws.end();
}

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding("ascii");

_input = "";

process.stdin.on("data", function (input) {
  _input += input;
});

process.stdin.on("end", function () {
  processData(_input);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On macOS Mojave the steps are:

1. On *Preferences* > *Keymap*, add a keyboard shortcut `Ctrl+D` to run the **Other** > **Send EOF** action; beware this may remove other actions associated to this shortcut, such as "Debug" (credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63955993/1159167))
2. Add the `Hello.js` file to your project and open it in the editor
3. Enter `Modify Run Configuration...` dialog (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>`, type "modify ..." and select it)

   1. make sure `Node interpreter:`, `Working directory:` and `JavaScript file:` are properly set
   2. (*if the solution writes output to a file*) Set also the `Environment variables:` to `OUTPUT_PATH=./hello.txt` or as desired
   3. Save it
4. Run the configuration. In the terminal pane that opens:

   1. provide the needed input; e.g. *4*, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>
   2. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to fire the `"end"` event
   3. check the generated file `hello.txt`

You may want to use `console.log()` to help debugging; make sure it's commented out before submitting your solution back to HackerRank.

---

Run Configuration:

[image]

Run Tool Window:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this works on windows, you can run it using node here end event gets triggered when you hit ctrl+D just like hackerrank or Mac os

```
'use strict';
const { METHODS } = require('http');
const readline = require('readline')
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');
readline.emitKeypressEvents(process.stdin);
let inputString = '';
let currentLine = 0;
process.stdin.setRawMode(false)
process.stdin.on('data', inputStdin => {
    inputString += inputStdin;
});
process.stdin.on('keypress', (str, key) => {
    if (key && key.ctrl && key.name == 'd'){
        inputString = inputString.trim().split('\n').map(string => {
            return string.trim();
        })
        main();  
    }
});
function readLine() {
    return inputString[currentLine++];
}
function method() {

}
function main() {
    const n = parseInt(readLine().trim());
    const arr = readLine().replace(/\s+$/g, '').split(' ').map(qTemp =>parseInt(qTemp,10))
    method();
}
```